# (Done) I think this closed question deserves another look

Tags: discussion, reopen-request

[Can I refuse to enter guests room if they're not wearing masks](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/171076/can-i-refuse-to-enter-guests-room-if-theyre-not-wearing-masks)

The core question is basic to the service industry not company specific, the details are not that important in my opinion. I think this should be reopened because it may get some more answers, but I don't want to be heavy handed with my jewelry.

I invite the community to have a look at the question and reopen it if they desire to.

Comment: I think it deserves addressing the elephant in the room, the fact the guest wearing a flimsy mask in a room they have been living in for the past 8 to 24h is doing exactly *nothing* for the safety of the employee. The only thing the employee can do is wear better PPE, and follow proper disinfectant protocol. The room is potentially contaminated, whether the guest puts on a flimsy mask for a minute or not. Masks are good when people meet in rooms where neither of them live, for example the hallway, the reception, the elevator or the gift shop.

Comment: @nvoigt thats is probably true enough, but the whole mask thing is largely irrelevant. The OP wants to confront guests without the boss knowing when there is no formal procedure to follow, which is the basic question, whether it's over a mask or peeing in the corridor makes no difference.

Comment: I've reopened it, I already have the communications gold tag badge so could do this even if I wasn't a mod.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Reopen" option is not present for me on that question, presumably because it was migrated from another site, and according to the blue banner at the top it was returned there.

[image]

I agree that it was an answerable question about how to navigate a workplace, so that's a shame.